# Two similar overloads? or one overload calling the other?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, overloading

I have a function that I would like to overload to take the same data in a different form, that is:

```
void encode(byte[,,],float)
```

and

```
void encode(Bitmap[],float)
```

I have written one overload of the function, and it is quite long(about 60 lines).

My question is, when writing the second overload, should I copy most of the code of the first overload and make little changes, or should I convert the data and call the first overload?

Comment: The latter. [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I agree, unless conversion is expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, avoid large repetitions.

One overload calling another, as you suggest, is often a good approach.

It can also often work well to factor out the commonality into a private method that both overloads call. This private method could be generic if necessary to allow for similar operations on different types.

There are though times when repetition is inevitable, particularly when overloading on the primitive types. Even here though see if you can factor out at least some of the functionality, or consider T4 templates.

Answer (score 2):

Never copy your code from a method to another one, It is a big mistake. For overloading you should make a method with most parameters and for other overloads call the one that has most parameters with some default values.